# JSP Getting a value

Tags: jsp, servlets

I just want to get the value of the String pass then put in the `<p></p>`. How to do that?

```
<% if(request.getParameter("status") != null) { %>
        <% if(request.getParameter("status").equals("ok")) { 
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");%>
            <p>put the value of pass here in this line</p>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the paragraph line with the code below

```
<p><%= pass%></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSTL

```
<c:out value="${pass}" />
```

Using scriptlets (less preferred)

```
<%= pass %>
```